# xwiki 10.5 issue for office server adding extensions

Tags: xwiki

Have upgraded to xwiki to 10.5 from 9.8 , got one new field in content panel office server but when added some extension office server which comes in content panel got disabled. What do I have to do for enable office server. Office server connectivity is established.

Thanks